# Jump to a specific position in a video using Android's Proximity Sensor

Tags: android, video, sensors

I want to use my HTC Explorer device to play a 5 minutes long video. Instead of using the built-in video player that comes with android, i am making my own app and using MediaPlayer to show the video.

The 5 minutes long video has different sections (its basically a video of a face doing different things like laughing, making a frown, etc).

I want to use the HTC Explorer's proximity sensor to detect whenever someone's hand moves close to the phone, thus making the video jump from one point to another (the face is laughing at minute 1, someone moves their hand close to the sensor thus making the video jump forward to minute 2 where the face is frowning).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [seekTo()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#seekTo(int)) on the [MediaPlayer](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html), to jump around.

For the proximity sensor bit, you could follow this:

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_position.html#sensors-pos-prox

You may want to do some windowing/averaging on the sensor values.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It is still a bit difficult to me, considering i dont know anything about android programming, but this puts me in the right path.